# Unable to install and configure a J-Link JTAG debugger on a Mac

Tags: jtag, segger-jlink

I have a Segger J-Link which I am trying to use on a Macbook running MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, with openocd and GDB against an ESP32 board. The problem is that I can not seen the device:

```
$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.JimsiPhone-WirelessiAP  /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART      /dev/cu.usbserial-0001
```

None of these is the J-Link. If I run lsusb I can see it:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 020 Device 002: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 020 Device 003: ID 1366:0101 SEGGER J-Link ARM
```

I have installed the "J-Link Software and Documentation Pack" downloaded from Segger. I have checked the Mac "Security and privacy" settings and it does not report that it blocked any drivers or programs from being installed or run.

On the J-Link, the green LED is on, with a very brief flash about twice per second.

I'm sure I have a piece missing, and would appreciate some help.

UPDATE: I have been following instructions here:

[OpenOCD Instructions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html#get-started-set-up-env)

It all works until I get to step 6, and I follow these instructions:

[Serial driver instructions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html)

The problem is, a path for the driver never shows up, as I described above. I don't think I can run OpenOCD if I can't make it talk to my J-link.

When I run openocd-esp32, I get (full paste from openocd-esp32 output is below):

```
Error: No J-Link device found.
```

The contents of esp32-wroom-32.cfg is:

```
echo "WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release."
set ESP32_FLASH_VOLTAGE 3.3
source [find target/esp32.cfg]
```

Here is the full paste:

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro-486:~ jim$ openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg -c "program_esp32 build/hello-world.bin 0x10000 verify exit"
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.10.0-esp32-20200420 (2020-04-20-16:15)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
Info : Configured 2 cores
Error: No J-Link device found.
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked

Assertion failed: (jtag_trst == 0), function jtag_checks, file src/jtag/core.c, line 343.
Abort trap: 6
```

Running JLinkExe does find the J-Link:

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro-486:~ jim$ JLinkExe
SEGGER J-Link Commander V6.80b (Compiled Jun  5 2020 17:42:04)
DLL version V6.80b, compiled Jun  5 2020 17:41:46

Connecting to J-Link via USB...Updating firmware:  J-Link V11 compiled Apr 23 2020 16:49:23
Replacing firmware: J-Link V11 compiled Aug 14 2019 16:21:09
Waiting for new firmware to boot
New firmware booted successfully
O.K.
Firmware: J-Link V11 compiled Apr 23 2020 16:49:23
Hardware version: V11.00
S/N: 51000936
License(s): GDB
VTref=0.000V


Type "connect" to establish a target connection, '?' for help
J-Link>
```

After doing the above I now get a different error message when running openocd-esp32 (perhaps because of the J-Link FW upgrade?). Initially it complained that there was not an adapter speed set, so I modified interface/jlink.cfg and added:

```
adapter_khz 3000
```

I now get a different error:

```
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones
```

Which I have been Googling, and which could mean a bad board or still another configuration issue. There is no SD card in the SD card socket and no other SPI devices on the board, although the ESP32-WROVER-32U has SPI flash on it.

Here is the complete output from openocd-esp32:

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro-486:~ jim$ openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg -c "program_esp32 build/hello-world.bin 0x10000 verify exit"
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.10.0-esp32-20200420 (2020-04-20-16:15)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 3000 kHz

WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
Info : Configured 2 cores
Info : J-Link V11 compiled Apr 23 2020 16:49:23
Info : Hardware version: 11.00
Info : VTarget = 0.000 V
Info : clock speed 3000 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: esp32.cpu0: IR capture error; saw 0x1f not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: esp32.cpu0: IR capture error; saw 0x1f not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Info : cpu0: Debug controller 0 was reset.
Info : cpu0: Core 0 was reset.
Error: esp32_soc_reset: Couldn't halt target before SoC reset
embedded:startup.tcl:449: Error: ** Unable to reset target **
in procedure 'program_esp32' 
in procedure 'program_esp' called at file "/Users/jim/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.10.0-esp32-20200420/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp32.cfg", line 64
in procedure 'program_error' called at file "/Users/jim/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.10.0-esp32-20200420/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg", line 75
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 449
Warn : Flash driver of esp32.flash does not support free_driver_priv()
Warn : Flash driver of esp32.irom does not support free_driver_priv()
Warn : Flash driver of esp32.drom does not support free_driver_priv()
```

Success! This circuit used the Segger 10 pin needle connector. On that connector pin 1 is VTREF and on my board it was left floating, when it should have been connected to V3.3. I connected it and:

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro-486:~ jim$ openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f board/esp32-wrover.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.10.0-esp32-20200420 (2020-04-20-16:15)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 1000 kHz

WARNING: boards/esp32-wrover.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
         If your board is ESP32-WROVER-KIT, use board/esp32-wrover-kit-1.8v.cfg instead.
Info : Configured 2 cores
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : J-Link V11 compiled Apr 23 2020 16:49:23
Info : Hardware version: 11.00
Info : VTarget = 3.290 V
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32: Debug controller 0 was reset.
Info : esp32: Core 0 was reset.
Info : esp32: Debug controller 1 was reset.
Info : esp32: Core 1 was reset.
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

Comment: What is the exact openocd command you are executing ? what is its exact output ?

Comment: I'm sorry I just saw your reply. I'll post an update to my question this evening, thank you.

Comment: @Frant I have added some details to my question.

Comment: I was more asking for a copy/paste of the exact openocd command you executed, as well as its output. Any reasons why you could not produce it ?

Comment: @Frant Sorry, I have added it. The error is that it can not find a J-Link device, which makes sense since there does not seem to be a path to it.

Comment: Since you installed the J-Link Software and Documentation Pack, can you see your JLink probe using JLink Commander ? Note that openocd is directly communicating with the JLink probe using USB, but this will validate your JLink is reachable, which should be the case.

Comment: Yes! Running JLinkExe found the hardware and updated its firmware, so the hardware is all working.

Comment: I tried to get JLinkExe to do something, but given the ESP32 is not officially supported I didn't make any progress. The first thing I need to do is verify that the JTAG connector on my board is wired correctly (Its a custom board).

Comment: But running openocd-esp32 now gives me different errors, and it appears that openocd-esp32 is finally talking to the J-Link hardware. New output from the command is posted above, thank you!

Comment: I never expected Segger to support the ESP32, this was just to make sure the JLink probe itself was working. Now that openocd is able to connect to your probe, you could just launch openocd using this command: `openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg` and verify you can  reset the ESP32, display registers,read/write memory.  You may have to check your wiring since openocd was unable to reset your target. Flashing the program should be done only once the above is working IMHO.

Comment: Oh I realized, and it did seem to solve the issue by updating the FW on the J-Link. When I run that I still get the "all ones" error so I assume there is a problem with my board. Is the "Info : VTarget = 0.000 V" message normal?

Comment: No, that means the JLink may not be properly wired to your system - see [here](https://www.visualmicro.com/page/ESP32-Debugging.aspx)  for double-checking your wiring.

Comment: I think, with your kind assistance, I got it! This board uses the Segger 10 pin needle connector and pin 1 (VTREF) was not connected. I added a hookup wire between V3.3 and that pin and got the results I pasted above. I'll now see if I can display registers and such (need to figure out how) but it's looking pretty good. If you care to leave an answer I'll be happy to accept it, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215966/discussion-between-frant-and-jim-archer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to validate your setup step by step - I personally do not like big bang integrations.

1. Verify that your the Segger software can see your JLink probe - the good thing is that `lsusb` can see it. JLink Commander should provide some useful information.
2. Launch openocd without any executable-related arguments: `openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg`
3. Verify that basic commands are working, i.e. resetting the CPU, displaying registers, reading/writing memory.
4. If you you are still experimenting issues, double-check your wiring - see [here](https://www.visualmicro.com/page/ESP32-Debugging.aspx) for more information.